# MVC3 access control

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, security, controls

I'm trying to disable/enable controls based on user permission using a custom security framework . I'm trying to use this code in the codebehind file

```
protected void OnLoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((ViewData[Constants.Permission]).Equals(Security.UserAccess.ReadOnlyAccess))
            {
                foreach (var control in this.Page.Controls  )
                {
                    control.IsReadOnly = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

But the IsReadOnly property of control is not available.  Is there a way I can fix this or a better way to achieve this?

---Update---

Controller.cs

```
    [Proxy.AimsAccessLevel]
    public ActionResult Edit(int clientId)
    {
        ClientId = clientId;
        //SetClientDetails();

        var Selection = new SelectionArgs(clientId, null);

        if (Selection.SelectionFlag == null || Selection.SelectionFlag == "N")
            Selection.EffectiveDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year + 1, 1, 1);

        return View(Selection); 
    }
```

proxy.cs

```
public class AccessLevel : AuthorizeAttribute
        {
            protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
            {
                Roles = Constants.AccessLevel.FullEdit + Constants.AccessLevel.ReadOnly.ToString() +
                        Constants.AccessLevel.RestrictedEdit;
                return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
            }
        }
```

Comment: MVC does not have a codebehind. Are you using MVC or WebForms?

Comment: im using mvc  i used <%@ Page CodeBehind="Edit.aspx.cs" Title=""  Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="Views.Selection.Edit" %>
has given me no errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be using codebehind with ASP.Net MVC - it goes against the principles of MVC.  A view should not be the thing deciding if a user has permissions or not.  Deciding if a page is viewable belongs at the controller level.

A better way to handle permissions is by using the `[Authorize]` attribute on your controllers.  Ie,

```
public MyController : Controller
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "admin")]  // Uses default FormsAuthentication
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

You can write your own `Authorize` attribute to tie into your custom framework:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization( AuthorizationContext filterContext )
    {
        // ... authorization stuff here ...
    }
}
```

Then use it on your controller action:

```
public HomeController : Controller
{
    [MyAuthorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I would add this override to the controller?

Comment: (fixed a bit of formatting).  No, the override does not go in your controller - that's part of the custom attribute.  The attribute then goes on the controller, or the controller action you wish to restrict.

Comment: I can't access the the source for the framework. It is being accessed via a webservice

Comment: Call the webservice from the attribute then.

Comment: I'm trying to use you approach but still am a bit lost, I have posted my changes above.

Comment: Roles expects a comma separated string - doesn't look like that's what you're setting.  Also, are you storing the user credential in the HttpContext's Identity?  That's where AuthorizeAttribute checks (HttpContext.User, set automatically with FormsAuthentication if you use that)  If not, then you'll have to validate the user role against whatever you're using to store the credential.